# jQuery v1.8.3 creating error in ie 8 and ie 7 "Unexpected call to method or property access."

Tags: javascript, jquery, script-debugging

In ie8 i am facing the problem in popup due to  this line in jquery v1.8.3

```
this.insertBefore( elem, this.firstChild );
```

Here is the function

```
prepend: function() {
        return this.domManip(arguments, true, function( elem ) {
            if ( this.nodeType === 1 || this.nodeType === 11 ) {
                this.insertBefore( elem, this.firstChild );
            }
        });
```

here is the screenshot of error.

[image]

thanx in advance

Comment: what HTML Element is `elem` and `this.firstChild`?

Comment: even i dont knw .its in jquery libery only

Comment: when the exception occurs, look in the locals tab. You should be able to find the tagName property for `elem` and `this`

Comment: but i can not change in jquery libeary so need solution accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IE8 cannot insert into html elements it doesn't recognise. 
It might be that there is a invalid markup, or it tries to insert a node into a HTML 5 tag.

If it's a HTML 5 tag, you can use a script like modernizr or html5shim to create the HTML 5 tags in IE.